# Algorithm for structural comparison of directed graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, graph

I'm looking for an algorithm/method to compare the structure of two directed graphs.
Each graph represents a procedure with the nodes being certain work steps. My aim is to compare two procedures and detect possible differences in a somewhat intelligent manner, meaning the algorithm should detect simple deviations like two interchanged work step or an additional work step in one of the graphs.

Initial situation:

- The number vertices of the two graphs may differ
- The weight all edges is the same
- A graph has up to 5k nodes
- The graphs are stored as pandas dataframe in python

Example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What would be the desired output for this picture? How do you store the graph?

Comment: you can run a depth-first search on both graphs simultaneously, and return false once you find a difference between 2 nodes?

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I updated the question since the fromer information was unclear

Comment: @Daniel True, but the problem is that structural differences, for example an additional node in one of the graphs, get carried on and subsequent comparisons of nodes always return a difference

Comment: you can perform some checking to guarantee you go to the same nodes at each step

Comment: Given that your graph is almost a tree, I would do a (possibly modified) DFS on each graph to make a DFS traversal list, and then use an [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm to find the operations needed to transform the first list to the second list.